# Is there a way to store and load formatted text from a text widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the output from using `.dump()` on a Text widget which uses formatting and I would like to use this to load it on another text widget. Is this possible or do I have to parse it back manually?
Example `.dump()` output: `[('mark', 'current', '1.0'), ('text', 'Sample text', '1.0'), ('mark', 'tk::anchor1', '1.11'), ('mark', 'insert', '1.11'), ('text', '\n', '1.11')]`

Comment: I dont think there is a built-in way as @Bryan said but do you want a way around? or do you just want to know if there is a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function to load that data in another text widget. You will have to write the code to parse it and reconstruct the data.